# How can I execute 3 threads in this order?

Tags: c, pthreads, thread-synchronization

I got a problem. I've tried for several days to execute 3 threads in this order in C: 
Thread 1
Thread 3
Thread 1
Thread 2
Thread 1

I use condition variables. This is my code, and just print:

Thread 1
Thread 3

And it stays blocked

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct node{
int val;
};

void * function(void *);
int turn = 1,var = 3;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  cond  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;


int main(){

int i;
pthread_t *pidthreads = NULL;

struct node *data;


pidthreads = (pthread_t *) calloc(3, sizeof(pthread_t));
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
for(i=1; i<=3; i++){
    data = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    data->val = i;
    pthread_create(&pidthreads[i], NULL, function, (void*)data);
    printf("Thread [%u] has been created\n", (unsigned int)pidthreads[i]);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    for(i=1; i<=3; i++)
    pthread_join(pidthreads[i], NULL);

return 0;
}

void * function( void *arg){
int myturn = ((struct node *)arg)->val;

pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
while(turn != myturn) pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);

printf("Thread %d\t[%u]\n", myturn, (unsigned int)pthread_self());

if(turn == 1){
    turn=var;
    var--;
}else{
    if(turn == 3){
        turn = 1;
    }else{
        if(turn == 2){
            turn = 1;
        }
    }
}

pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

}
```

I don't really know how to do this. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Some `volatile`s missing

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Given that there is no access to memory mapped device registers, I fail to see how `volatile` could apply, keeping in mind that `volatile` is neither necessary nor sufficient for accessing objects from multiple threads.

Comment: Is there a practical application for this? If so, you may want to rethink your design. Mandating certain threads execute in a specific order doesn't sound conducive to a parallelized problem, and if you don't have a parallelized problem threads won't help you. Looks like a single-threaded state machine is all you need here. A large percentage of your critical section code is devoted towards deciding which thread to execute next rather than doing useful work.

Comment: @yano it's an assignment for sure.

Comment: Yes, it's an assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a loop in your function like this.

```
int myturn = ((struct node *)arg)->val;

while(true){ // add loop

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while(turn != myturn) pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
    ....
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

But you have to add the conditions to leave.

```
while(true){

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    // conditions to leave the waitting loop
    while(turn != myturn && turn!=0) pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);

    if(turn==0) { // conditions to leave the infinite loop
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        break;
    }
    printf("Thread %d\t[%u]\n", myturn, (unsigned int)pthread_self());
    ...
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

Comment: Thank youuu very much. you helped me a lot.